# resample algorithm for linear array (json)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with 300 elements. This is bars of waveform. 300 bars equal 300px.

```
[28,26,22,20,28,22,20,24,24,25,23,28,20,29,29,31,31,25,23,18,22,26,27,28,23,26,19,22,24,27,24,27,25,25,22,34,34,31,32,37,37,33,34,35,29,33,32,30,32,34,39,34,32,32,32,33,34,37,38,36,36,36,35,36,32,36,34,36,35,35,33,36,34,34,37,35,33,34,33,31,35,35,33,34,36,36,34,33,35,33,35,36,35,34,30,30,31,34,37,35,36,33,25,31,34,30,25,40,33,25,31,30,26,41,34,28,33,30,24,20,28,27,18,32,27,30,39,35,31,33,29,32,31,31,34,31,42,34,28,35,35,38,38,33,27,38,38,37,43,32,38,38,35,36,41,34,30,21,21,22,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,20,21,21,20,21,21,21,22,22,20,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,29,37,39,39,30,38,29,29,35,40,33,41,41,33,36,35,28,30,36,32,32,31,35,30,32,29,29,30,31,32,33,34,33,32,29,30,31,29,27,28,29,28,28,30,28,28,22,28,29,25,24,25,30,32,30,30,28,28,25,28,27,24,23,25,32,30,32,28,26,28,30,28,30,28,29,26,29,29,26,32,29,26,26,30,27,27,24,27,28,33,38,35,24,35,27,21,23,23,28,20,23,28,21,24,18,22,22,23,22,19,27,16,18,37,59,59]
```

I want reduce evenly 50,100,250 elements and get ~250px ~100px ~50px

I am looking resampling algorithm for array like Nearest neighbour but I don't know how apply it on linear array

Example: http://codepen.io/Alexufo/pen/MyKpXO

Comment: What is the problem than ?

Comment: I think resampling would be the keyword to look for here.

Comment: @n01ze i am looking resampling  algorithm for array like Nearest neighbour but I don't know how apply it on linear array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE 2021:** I did a repo https://github.com/Alexufo/Responsive-waveform

I found what I wanted.

Downsample algorithm largest Triangle Three Buckets.
Very easy to use `largestTriangleThreeBuckets(data, threshold)`

http://flot.base.is/

http://flot.base.is/jquery.flot.downsample.js

And this is interesting too: http://mourner.github.io/simplify-js/

I just set data and threshold and I get downsampled array.

[image]

Comment: i searched this for the exact same use case, thanks for sharing

Comment: @cinatic I did a repo https://github.com/Alexufo/Responsive-waveform

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to easily remove every 6th element from the array.

```
myArray = myArray.filter((e,i) => i%6)
```

Edit: for a more general case

```
function reduceArray(array, newLength) {
  if(newLength >= array.length) {
    return array.slice();
  }
  var factor = array.length / (array.length - newLength)
  return array.filter((e,i) => Math.floor(i % factor));
}
```

Need to round because factor might not be an integer. The if statement is there, since it would always remove at least one element otherwise. I'm using slice so I won't return a reference to the original array, but a new copy.

Comment: thanks. But what we can do if i need evenly reduce width more then 50%?

Answer (score -1):

You can try `Array.map`

```js
var data = [28,26,22,20,28,22,20,24,24,25,23,28,20,29,29,31,31,25,23,18,22,26,27,28,23,26,19,22,24,27,24,27,25,25,22,34,34,31,32,37,37,33,34,35,29,33,32,30,32,34,39,34,32,32,32,33,34,37,38,36,36,36,35,36,32,36,34,36,35,35,33,36,34,34,37,35,33,34,33,31,35,35,33,34,36,36,34,33,35,33,35,36,35,34,30,30,31,34,37,35,36,33,25,31,34,30,25,40,33,25,31,30,26,41,34,28,33,30,24,20,28,27,18,32,27,30,39,35,31,33,29,32,31,31,34,31,42,34,28,35,35,38,38,33,27,38,38,37,43,32,38,38,35,36,41,34,30,21,21,22,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,20,21,21,20,21,21,21,22,22,20,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,29,37,39,39,30,38,29,29,35,40,33,41,41,33,36,35,28,30,36,32,32,31,35,30,32,29,29,30,31,32,33,34,33,32,29,30,31,29,27,28,29,28,28,30,28,28,22,28,29,25,24,25,30,32,30,30,28,28,25,28,27,24,23,25,32,30,32,28,26,28,30,28,30,28,29,26,29,29,26,32,29,26,26,30,27,27,24,27,28,33,38,35,24,35,27,21,23,23,28,20,23,28,21,24,18,22,22,23,22,19,27,16,18,37,59,59]

var baseValue=300;

function reduceValues(arr, val){
  return data.map(function(item){
    return Math.ceil(item * val / baseValue);
  });
}

function print(o){
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(o,0,4) + "</pre>";
}

function getNewList(val){
  print(reduceValues(data.slice(), val));
}
```

```html
<button onclick="getNewList(50)">50</button>
<button onclick="getNewList(100)">100</button>
<button onclick="getNewList(150)">150</button>
<button onclick="getNewList(200)">200</button>
<button onclick="getNewList(250)">250</button>
<button onclick="getNewList(300)">300</button>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: @Alexufo didn't get you. Per my understanding, parent array, `data` still has original values and you need updated values array. Right?